# One degree self map on $S^1$ but is not diffeomorpism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, manifolds, diffeomorphism

I want to find a map $F:\mathbb{S}^1\to\mathbb{S}^1$ such that $\text{deg}(F)=1$ and $F$ is not a diffeomorphism. Could $F$ be $F(x,y)=(|x|,y)$?

Comment: Identity map is a diffeomorphism, so it can't be identity

Comment: I understand nothing. What is $\deg(F)$ if $F$ is not a diffeomorphism? And if $F(e^{i\theta})=e^{i\theta}$ then $F$ is the identity function, how could it not be a diffeomorphism?

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow Any hints on what it should be?

Comment: Any map that is homotopic to the identity but is not 1-1. Very easy to visualize.

Comment: I think the difficulty you're having with this is that you're thinking of the circle as a particular subspace of $\mathbf{R}^2$. It is much easier to write down the map you'd like explicitly if you consider $S^1=[0,1]/\{0\sim 1\}$.

Comment: @ajotatxe, there is no point in having a definition of degree that only applies to diffeomorphisms. In this case you can define degree in terms of top homology, or as the Browser degree, or with top de Rham cohomology. All of them are equivalent.

Comment: Which definition of degree do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't work because it's not surjective. Any curve you push foward with $F$ will be a curve in a punctured circle, which is the line. So they will have trivial homology. In terms of explicit examples of $F$, my first thought was the use cohomology:

It's sufficient to find a function $F$ so that $F^*d\theta$ has the cohomology generated by $d\theta$ but with some zeros (as a 1-form). Here, I'm thinking that $\theta$ is the identity on the real line modulo integer multiples of $2\pi$.

E.g, setting $\nu = f d\theta $, the equation $F^*d\theta = \nu$ boils down to $F' = f$. One can take $f = \cos(2\theta) + 1$, which has a solution $F =-1/2 \sin{2\theta} + \theta$ on our circle. Note that $f$ has integral $2\pi$ on our circle and has zeros. Thus $F$ has your properties.